# Move SKSpriteNode position across multiple scenes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have two scenes with scenery where clouds (SKSpriteNodes) move on the x-axis. When I change scenes they reset to their initial position.

**How can I pass the x-position to the new scene when I move scenes?**

This is my code. Both scenes have the same code and structure.

Thanks, guys!

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    addScene()
    addMenuButtons()
    addSocial()

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if self.cloud01.position.x < self.cloud01.size.width * -1 {
        self.cloud01.position.x = self.frame.size.width + (self.cloud01.size.width / 2)
    } else {
        self.cloud01.position.x -= 0.5
    }

    if self.cloud02.position.x < self.cloud02.size.width * -1 {
        self.cloud02.position.x = self.frame.size.width + (self.cloud02.size.width / 2)
    } else {
        self.cloud02.position.x -= 0.3
    }

    if self.cloud03.position.x < self.cloud03.size.width * -1 {
        self.cloud03.position.x = self.frame.size.width + (self.cloud03.size.width / 2)
    } else {
        self.cloud03.position.x -= 0.4
    }
}

func addScene() {

    self.cloud01.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.cloud01.size.width = self.frame.size.width / 3
    self.cloud01.size.height = self.cloud01.size.width / 5
    self.cloud01.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 50)

    self.cloud02.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.cloud02.size.width = self.frame.size.width / 3
    self.cloud02.size.height = self.cloud01.size.width / 5
    self.cloud02.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - 50, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 200)

    self.cloud03.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.cloud03.size.width = self.frame.size.width / 3
    self.cloud03.size.height = self.cloud01.size.width / 5
    self.cloud03.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 50, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 125)

    self.addChild(self.cloud01)
    self.addChild(self.cloud02)
    self.addChild(self.cloud03)
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to store the clouds (and there positions) in an array then you can just pass the array between scenes, but if it was me I would probably create a background scene with the clouds and overlay the other two scenes over the top as required - it depends on whether sprites from those scenes interact with the clouds or whether they are just background

Comment: Makes sense, @Paulw11! But the same question goes for the array. How do I pass it along multiple scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press Button from first Scene you can store cloud's positions into `NSUserDefaults` this way into `touchBegan` method:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playButton {

            let cloud1Pos = cloud01.position
            let cloud2Pos = cloud02.position
            let cloud3Pos = cloud03.position

            NSUserDefaults().setObject(NSStringFromCGPoint(cloud1Pos), forKey: "cloud1Pos")
            NSUserDefaults().setObject(NSStringFromCGPoint(cloud2Pos), forKey: "cloud2Pos")
            NSUserDefaults().setObject(NSStringFromCGPoint(cloud3Pos), forKey: "cloud3Pos")

            let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
            let letsPlay = playScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(letsPlay, transition: reveal)
        }
    }
}
```

After that when new scene is load into view the you can read stored values:

```
let cloud1Pos = CGPointFromString(NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("cloud1Pos") as! String)
let cloud2Pos = CGPointFromString(NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("cloud2Pos") as! String)
let cloud3Pos = CGPointFromString(NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("cloud3Pos") as! String)
```

Now you have all cloud's position so you can assign that position to your cloud:

```
func addScene() {

    self.cloud01.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.cloud01.size.width = self.frame.size.width / 3
    self.cloud01.size.height = self.cloud01.size.width / 5
    self.cloud01.position = cloud1Pos

    self.cloud02.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.cloud02.size.width = self.frame.size.width / 3
    self.cloud02.size.height = self.cloud01.size.width / 5
    self.cloud02.position = cloud2Pos

    self.cloud03.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.cloud03.size.width = self.frame.size.width / 3
    self.cloud03.size.height = self.cloud01.size.width / 5
    self.cloud03.position = cloud3Pos

    self.addChild(self.cloud01)
    self.addChild(self.cloud02)
    self.addChild(self.cloud03)
}
```

And One suggestion for you. Don't update cloud position from Update method instead of that you can make one function like `updatePosOfCloud` and you can run that function into `didMoveToView` method this way:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(updatePosOfCloud), SKAction.waitForDuration(0.05)])))
```

I have did this in my sample project.

[HERE](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Set-Position-of-Sprite-From-First-View) is complete working project.

**EDIT:**

As [Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) suggested you can do it this way too:

declare global variables above the class declaration of your first scene:

```
var cloud1Position : CGPoint?
var cloud2Position : CGPoint?
var cloud3Position : CGPoint?
```

This can store your clouds position and when button is pressed you can assign the position of clouds to this variables this way:

```
cloud1Position = cloud01.position
cloud2Position = cloud02.position
cloud3Position = cloud03.position
```

In your second scene you can assign position to clouds:

```
self.cloud01.position = cloud1Position!
self.cloud02.position = cloud2Position!
self.cloud03.position = cloud3Position!
```

you can use any way to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Using `NSUserDefaults` to pass transient data between objects is pretty awful.  Why not just create an object to store the cloud's positions and share this object between the two scenes, probably via the view controller.

Comment: @Paulw11 How do I do that, Paul?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Dharmesh, thanks for that. I have one issue: the two scenes are in two seperate .swift files. How can I pass it to another file?